# What type of connector is this, and how to connect cable into it?

Tags: connector

The remote control for the boiler fall into the flor and one of the cables got disconnected from a connector. I don't know how am I supposed to put it back in, because the red seems to be really well placed, but I can't put the black.

This is the picture of the connector, and I would like to know what type of connector is it and also how to properly put the black cable in.

[image]

Comment: A view of the front of the connector is more important then of the back!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an insulation displacement type connector. It works because when the black wire is pushed into the "jaws" of the metal knife edges, it cuts through the insulation and makes an interference contact with the conductor inside the wire.

[image]

Normally a tool is used but you may be able to get a blunt instrument and push the black wire back into place. I'd probably solder it afterwards to ensure the connection is good BUT make sure the plastic case can withstand the heat without distorting.

Comment: Do I need to peel the black cable so the wire makes contact with the connector at all?

Comment: @Nobita No, the knife edges (or jaws) cut through the insulation and make contact with the conductor.

Comment: Ok, so I need to push the black cable really strong so the edges cut the insulation. Oh man, I don't know what I'm doing :D

Comment: Try it - you've got nothing to lose. I regularly use a screw driver that has a blunt blade whose width is slightly less than the gap between the pairs of blades.

Comment: I am not able to push de black cable into the connector. What's the alternative? :D

Comment: @Nobita then I would say you have to strip back the insulation and force open the blades a little and solder the wire to the terminals (or just try pushing harder).

Comment: It worked, I was pushing from the wrong place. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the red wire is pushed in from the side where the metal blades cut through the insulation to make contact and grip the cable.

Do the same with the black, trim off the exposed copper, make sure the hole is empty of debris and use something but thing to push the wire into place.

Don't forget to do a continuity test afterwards.

Comment: What is the 'exposed copper'?

Comment: The little bit of wire sticking out at the end.